# Excel vba for-loop large search

Tags: excel, for-loop, vba

I’m trying to do a search for a lot of variables. If within a small code set up. Basically I need to search each row for a combination of variables in a certain column. Ie Y2, Y4, Y6, ...... up to 200 then it needs to switch and look for N1, N3, N5 ...... up to 200 again I have tried using a for loop but after it hits the first variable it quits. Here is the loop I have been trying to get to work.

```
AllNo =1
Do Until AllNo = 200
    Checking = “N” & AllNo
    For CheckNum = 2 to RowEnd
           If Cells(CheckNum, 8) = Checking Then
                      Rows(CheckNum).Select
                      Userform 1.Show
           End if 
     Next CheckNum
     AllNo = AllNo + 2 
Loop
```

Sorry if I miss typed something putting this in from my phone.  Any help would be great thank you.

Comment: What is supposed to happen when you find the item?

Comment: It is to allow you to check the row of information, add “verified” to the next column, and then continue checking for the next one that meets the criteria.

Comment: If you want to find a cell containing something specific, just use the `Find` method instead of looping like this.

Comment: You can also filter the column, then loop through the filtered items.  Maybe more information could be supplied